# Adding nested JSON to Angular UI-Grid

Tags: json, angular, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I am trying to add the following sample JSON to UI-Grid and am wondering what the best way to go about doing that would be, here is a snippet of the format:

```
{
"JSON": {
    "name": "ROOT",
    "type": "ROOT",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "temp",
            "type": "Account"
        },
        {
            "name": "temp",
            "type": "Account"
        },
        {
            "name": "PARENT",
            "type": "Group",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Test",
                    "type": "Account"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Test",
                    "type": "Account"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Test",
                    "type": "Account"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Test",
                    "type": "Account"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Test",
                    "type": "Account"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Test",
                    "type": "Account"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Test",
                    "type": "Account"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Test",
                    "type": "Account"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Test",
                    "type": "Account"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Test",
                    "type": "Account"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Test",
                    "type": "Account"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Test",
                    "type": "Account"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Test",
                    "type": "Account"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Test",
                    "type": "Account"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Test",
                    "type": "Account"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Test",
                    "type": "Account"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "PARENT",
            "type": "Group",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "TEST",
                    "type": "Account"
                },
                {
                    "name": "TEST",
                    "type": "Account"
                },
                {
                    "name": "TEST",
                    "type": "Account"
                },
                {
                    "name": "TEST",
                    "type": "Account"
                },
                {
                    "name": "FACILITY",
                    "type": "Account"
                },
                {
                    "name": "FACILITY",
                    "type": "Account"
                },
                {
                    "name": "FACILITY",
                    "type": "Account"
                },
                {
                    "name": "TEST",
                    "type": "Account"
                },
                {
                    "name": "FACILITY",
                    "type": "Account"
                }
            ]
        }
}
```

I get the data in my component rather easily through a service call:

```
public getBssGridData() {
     this.bssService.getBssResults().then(response => {
         // response holds the json file listed above
         let data = response;
     });
}
```

This data will be the row name, so it will sit to the far left of the row and define the row (left to right) names. Essentially each "name" property in the JSON will show as the row title.

I need to be able to show the root node name (ROOT) when the grid loads initially and then click to expand so I can see each rows next list of children.

Property "type" means it is a leaf node, property "group" means it has children.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far with the grid? Create a plnkr so that the community can help you better.

Comment: Please review: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/106_binding, http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/216_expandable_grid. Do these help with what you are trying to accomplish?